# Pascal linked list to linked list does not work

Tags: pointers, linked-list, pascal, lazarus

These are two linked lists that I've made,for a school project...
I want the first list to be called from the second,I have done that and at the compile time everything is ok. When I run it it says :
Project (myProject) raised exception class 'External: SIGSEGV'.
At address 40D32D 
Here is my code:

```
   list2=^ptr;
   ptr=record
       vlera:integer;
       pozicioni:integer;
   end;

type
   list=^pointer;
   pointer=record
       rreshti:list2;
   end;
   var
     a:array[1..7] of list;
     i:integer;
     kjovlere:list2;

begin
    for i:=1 to 7 do begin
        a[i]:=@kjovlere;
        write('Give the pozition for the row:',i,' : ');
        read(a[i]^.rreshti^.pozicioni);
        write ('give the value for this poziton :');
        read(a[i]^.rreshti^.vlera);
        writeln;
    end;
end.
```

And the error is at the for loop,at the `read(a[i]^.rreshti^.pozicioni);`
I would be very thankful if anyone explains me or gives me any suggestion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The provided source code shows at least two misunderstandings about pointer management in Pascal.**

> **Main Problem** - To assign data, a `record` type shall be allocated before.

This problem is referring to the lines `read(a[i]^.rreshti^.pozicioni);` and `read(a[i]^.rreshti^.vlera);`.

Both `a[i]` and `rreshti` are declared as pointer type (`list=^pointer;` & `list2=^ptr;`) and shall be allocated to a record structure before assigning data.

*Step1*: allocate the `a[i]` pointer in the loop.

```
new(a[i]);
```

*Step2*: allocate the `a[i]^.rreshti` pointer in the loop.

```
new(a[i]^.rreshti);
```

> **Strange Problem** - Assign a pointer to a `record` type shall respect the destination type.

This problem is referring to the line `a[i]:=@kjovlere;`.

The `a[i]` is a `list` which is `list=^pointer;` and not `list2` (`list2=^ptr;`) as declared for `kjovlere:list2;`.

Solution is: remove that line `a[i]:=@kjovlere;`.

> **Solution:**

```
begin
    for i:=1 to 7 do begin
        (* a[i]:=@kjovlere; to be removed *)
        new(a[i]);
        new(a[i]^.rreshti);
        write('Give the pozition for the row:',i,' : ');
        read(a[i]^.rreshti^.pozicioni);
        write ('give the value for this poziton :');
        read(a[i]^.rreshti^.vlera);
        writeln;
    end;
end.
```

Comment: J. Piquard thanks a lot,for all the explanation you have done.. :)